# docker push fails with status 400

Tags: docker, boot2docker

My boot2docker push is failing with the following error.

```
Error: Status 400 trying to push repository abc/pentaho1: "Access denied: 8dc6a04270dfb41460bd53968e31b14da5414501c935fb67cf25975af9066925 is a private image"
```

my username on dockerhub is abc.
I created an image with tag abc/pentaho1/

These are the steps i followed to push the image:

```
docker build -t abc/pentaho1
docker login (successful)
docker push abc/pentaho1:latest
```

(I also tried the push command without the word latest)

I created a repository on my dockerhub with name pentaho1. It is not private.
Yet i see the above error.

Also i tried the following command. the results are empty.

```
bash-3.2$ docker images -a | grep 

    8dc6a04270dfb41460bd53968e31b14da5414501c935fb67cf25975af9066925
    bash-3.2$
```

Can somebody help.

Comment: You should report this to https://support.docker.com/ since this is a hub issue.

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be resolved by upgrading to docker 1.6